# Laravel5: Auth::attempt not working as expected

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

i've read the [Laravel 5 Docs about Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) but couldn't manage to Login as described.

My users table contains both fields, username and password (which is type TEXT), i've stored a hashed password which is like `$2y$10$XCyEOyvC6Yp/O6HaeemPheO4KV1I8aEMUytZZt77Yjw9hp/j6uivWnope`

here's my code:

```
public function validateLogin()
{
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $pass = Input::get('password');
    $pass = Hash::make($pass);

    $credentials = [
            'username' => $email,
            'password' => $pass
    ];
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return "passed";
    }else{
        return "nope";
    }
}
```

I've tried anything, `Auth::attempt` always returns false :(
Imo it's exactly as described in the Docs, anyone knows what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: check you users table and config/auth.php  Authentication Table Users

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to do the `$pass = Hash::make($password)` call by yourself.

Try removing that line see if it works.

From the docs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first
>   argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in
>   your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be
>   retrieved by the value of the email column. **If the user is found,
>   the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the
>   hashed password value passed to the method via the array**.

For further reference check:

http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 0):

did u write the function in AuthController? or in any new/other controller?

if u wrote the function in other controller make sure you have added this code at top

```
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;




public function login()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
        else{
             return redirect()->intended('admin/login');
        }
    }
```